# Handlebars.js/Foundation 6 Template return strange error while using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, handlebars.js, browser-sync

I'm currently working on a project which uses ajax heavily, for basically everything, from fetching JSON via REST API, to loading individual pages and templates.

Everything is going smoothly to a point, where I want to replace `<a href='partial.html?id={{id}}'></a>` (which works like a charm [I mean the handlebared id]) with simplest of AJAX functions

My **ajax** for this task is as follows

```
function ajaxLoad(url){
    var main = ('#main-content');
    main.html('');
    main.load(url);
}
```

and corresponding **call** looks like this

```
<div class="abc" onclick="ajaxLoad('partial.html?id={{id}}')></div>
```

It should work just fine, shouldn't it? Well, return I got is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data842678246728406 [or some other seemingly random number]' of null
```

for a `browser-sync-client`.

Other than that, every AJAX call is running perfectly.

I tried to rebuild the `ajaxLoad` function, I tried fixing it by loading a clean file without any `?id=` parameters and such, to no avail.

Do you, good people, have any idea where might be the problem, or even what is going on here?

Comment: Should your main variable be jQuery? $("#main-content")? Also, it looks like this is in load but has to do with the data. Can you show the object you are using?